# Can anyone help me by providing a sample python-script to modify the size of anyone feature in this Blender model 3D model of Humanoid

Tags: python, rigging, bones

I have a project deadline and I want to change the scaling of this humanoid model using a python script only, I want to select the specific bones of the "metarig" object and increase or decrease its scaling by setting values in the script for its length or width.
I am totally new to Blender that is why I am asking for a sample script, rest i shall modify the script for other bones in the rig, so if anyone can write a script and show me  how we can select and modify scaling for one bone, that would be of great help.
You can find the blender object here,
https://free3d.com/3d-model/rigged-male-human-442626.html

Comment: Would it still help you if I answered this in 9-11 hours?

Comment: surely, i would be waiting for your answer sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented in your previous question (or dublicate), [ManuelbastioniLAB](http://www.manuelbastioni.com/faq.php)  will probably suffice. You can change a lot of parameters in there, which you can also access via script.

[image]

[image]

To get information of how to access a certain parameter, just hover above it and press CTRL+C (if that doesn't work copy it by hand).

A short example of how you could change a parameter:

```
import bpy

def buttock_depth_Y(size):
    bpy.data.objects["f_ca01"].buttock_depth_Y = size
    bpy.ops.mbast.measures_apply()
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    buttock_depth_Y(9999)
```

To run the script either make a .py file with the code in it or do it in the scripting layout

[image]

Comment: @ShreyanshDubey If it answers your question you can accept it :)